# Installing SQL Server 2012 error "The system cannot open the device or file specified."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 Developer on my machine which already has SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Windows 7.

I used Microsoft Secure Download Manager for downloading installer and it automatically convert installer file to ISO file. I am using WinRAR to unzip the ISO file and running setup on installation I got below error message:

> Unable to open Windows Installer file 'C:\SQLSErverInstaller\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst_msi\sql_engine_core_inst.msi'.
>
> Windows Installer error message: The system cannot open the device or file specified.
>
> Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.

On clicking retry I couldn't do installation but it failed.

Looking into directory I could find `sql_engine_core_inst` file. Clicking it I was not able to run it and got message

> This installation package couldn't be opened. Contact the application vender to verify that this is a valid windows package.

I tried to download installer many times but every time got same error, please help me.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Go to Security section of the General tab by right-clicking and selecting Properties of the setup file and select "Unblock"

Comment: Quantum Elf, Under security there is no Unblock option. Please guide.

Comment: @haansi - Right-click your .msi file and on the General tab (first tab that opens), there is a Security field at the bottom with an "Unblock" button. It should be there...

Comment: @QuantumElf Nope, I have this problem and there is no security or unblock option for me either.

Comment: @QuantumElf, I have also same problem and there is security button above the general button but no unblock button please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you copy the entire installation Out of the ISO and onto hard disk, where, you will be able to see the security options (which mine didn't need changing) but the installation should work properly as it has proper access to the files.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while installing SQL server. The workaround is just to remove SQL 2012 Native Client from the installed programs list. Then started reinstallation.

Answer (score -2):

the missing file its included in SQLEXPRWT_x(your WIN flavor)_ESN.exe

SQLEXPRWT_x86_ESN.exe