# WHat Can I do ? During Installing MSSQl server 2014 brings message . An error was encountered. The system cannot read from the specified device

Tags: sql-server

WHat Can I do ? During Installing Microsoft SQl server 2014 express brings message . An error was encountered. The system cannot read from the specified device

Comment: Which device? Can you add, in your question, the exact error message?

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I download SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe from microsoft page and pu ti in folder in D disk and try the the same in C Disk. But in both cases I got an error "An error was encountered. The system cannot read from the specified device", when I try to run .exe file as administrator .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to read this questions and try the answers: 
[Installing SQL Server 2012 error "The system cannot open the device or file specified."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724160/installing-sql-server-2012-error-the-system-cannot-open-the-device-or-file-spec)

Comment: It doesnt help.

Comment: I download the same file again and now there is no problem )) . Thank You .